# Custom z-index for v-dialog

Tags: css, vuetify.js

When I use Vuetify's `v-dialog`, my page's heading is positioned on top of the dialog. For example:

[image]

I can't easily change the heading's `z-index` since this is an old codebase. So I tried to override the dialog's z-indexes like this:

```
.v-overlay { z-index: 20001 !important; }
.v-dialog__content { z-index: 20002 !important; }
```

This works visually, but now "click outside to close" doesn't work. Here is an example:

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
  vuetify : new Vuetify(),
    el: "#app",
  data: { dialog: false },
});
```

```css
.banner {
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:20px;
  background-color:red;
  /* z-index:1000; */
}

/** This fixes the banner, but now it won't close. **/
.v-overlay {
  z-index: 1001 !important;
}
.v-dialog__content {
  z-index: 1002 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.30/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <div class='banner'>Banner</div>
    <div style="height:30px;">&nbsp;</div>
    <v-dialog v-model='dialog'>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">Show</v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>
          Click outside should close.
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This Vuetify update](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/1932) makes it simple:

```
<v-dialog v-model='dialog' style='z-index:20001;'>
```

The dialog, backdrop, and content will automatically get the z-indexes set correctly and the "click outside to close" works as well.

Comment: This didn't work for me for some reason. The style is never applied

Comment: @ObedMarquezParlapiano yeah, same for me - upgraded to `2.5.10` and it stopped working

Comment: sounds like this was a temporary hack only :(

Comment: Strange, fix is working for me in 2.5.14. But I think this is quite hacky. As we embed vuetify in our older CSS-environment, every dialog must have this fix, which less than optimal. Just using CSS to target v-overlay does not seem to work... 

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a hack, but you could add a class to the banner that is triggered based on the v-dialog's model, like so:

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
  vuetify : new Vuetify(),
    el: "#app",
  data: { dialog: false },
});
```

```css
.banner {
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:20px;
  background-color:red;
  z-index:1000;
}

/** Add a class to reset the z-index to inherit (or whatever works with your code base) **/
.banner-dialog {
    z-index: inherit;
}

/** I removed the z-index from the core Vue component classes. **/
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.30/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    // Add a class here to trigger based on the v-dialog model
    <div :class="{ 'banner-dialog': dialog }" class='banner'>Banner</div>
    <div style="height:30px;">&nbsp;</div>
    <v-dialog v-model='dialog'>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">Show</v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>
          Click outside now closes!
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The banner isn't in my Vue instance but I could do something similar by watching `dialog` and adding/removing the class. For me the challenge is the banner is just one of several conflicting z-indexes so it'd be messy to change them all

Comment: I see. Yes, this can be quite a challenge with an old code base. Good luck!