# Vuetify: v-data-table overlaps v-dialog

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm experiencing a weird behavior when a `v-dialog` is placed above an `v-data-table`.
The Text "No data present" is above the v-dialog and im able to click it. If im in mobile view, the table sorting also is above the the v-dialog.

[image: Overlapping text]

I noticed even and expanded v-data-table item is completly overlapping a dialog
[image]

I tried to work it around with z-indexes like this ( i tried various v-data-table css classes ) but it changes nothing.

```
.v-dialog {
  z-index: 3000 !important;
};
.v-data-table {
  z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

The only workaround i found, was to disable `v-data-table header` and `no-data-text` when a dialog is opened ( or the complete `v-data-table` ). But for me this isn't a real solution.

I created a CodePen to reproduce the problem but with cdn's it works without any problems.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/LiVion-the-vuer/pen/bGZrXva)

I'm currently using this versions:

**vue 2.7.13** 
**vuetify 2.6.12**

Comment: Hmm, in your CodePen, when I open the dialog and move it around (by adjusting vertical height of the output panel), I does not look like the dialog is overlapped. The "No data available" text, a table header, the sort panel in mobile view - all seem to stay below the dialog. Am I missing something?

Comment: Jep, as i wrote `... but with cdn's it works without any problems`

I can't really comprehend why this is happening

Comment: I possibly found an solution. Since the css variant of changing the `z-index` wont work, i tried it with the `style` parameter inside the `v-dialog` as noticed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64159591/custom-z-index-for-v-dialog . After playing around with it i found out, that if i change the `v-dialog` index to `9997` it works and when i change it to `9996` it is in the same layer as the `expanded item` and the `no-data-text`